# Heritage Wheat flours- Hydration?

Tags: bread

I use Red fife Heritage wheat in my baking.
I grow, mill, and sift our own wheat. what are peoples experiences with the differences between Heritage wheat's and conventional wheat's in bread baking.
I have noticed that the Hydration is different... sometimes it seems like the flour hydrates quickly then for lack of a better word "releases" some of the hydration leaving a liquid layer on the outside of the dough... has anyone else had this experience?

Comment: You would have to define conventional wheat and what you are comparing. Are you comparing home-milled flour in both cases?

Comment: Isn’t that just the autolyse process happening?

Comment: It may just be the autolyse but is seems like a lot of liquid....I use 25% of the home grown and sift red fife in my breads... the other flour is 25% all purpose and 50% ultimate performer by Guisto's